# VBA Userform: Data Entry

Tags: database, excel, vba, userform

I have looked all over and cannot seem to find an answer or solution to this question and was hoping you could help.

I have a excel worksheet with raw data. I would like this data to populate onto a Userform, where I can then add additional data, and have this then populate onto another worksheet in the same workbook.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thank you in advance for taking your time to consider.

Excel Newbie, Finger crossed for an answer!

Comment: Yes this is possible.  What is the data from the worksheet being populated into on the userform?  A combobox?  A text area?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, but you need to familiarize yourself with range notation. For example,

```
Textbox1.text = Sheet1.Range("A1").formulaR1C1
```

Then to put the data onto another sheet,

```
Sheet2.Range("A1").formulaR1C1 = Textbox1.Text
```